# Plot residuals in R

Tags: r, plot, statistics, regression

I want to add the lines between the reggression line and the points in the figure but I don't find a solution.

This is my currently plot

[image]

```
zz_fm <-lm(x ~ y)
plot(y,x, xlim = c(0,100),ylim=c(0,110))
abline(zz_fm, col ="green")
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: Relevant post? https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/53254/how-to-find-residuals-and-plot-them What is the expected output?

Comment: Try plot(y,x, xlim = c(0,100),ylim=c(0,110))
abline(resid(zz_fm), col ="green")

Comment: What for? you make regression so you can plot fitted values over residuals. You see residuals on your plot as a distance between the line and the point.

Comment: Linked Q is not an _exact_ duplicate, but the stats.SE link is a duplicate. take your pick

Comment: @Aleksandr, your solution doesn't work. I don't know if it's clear what I want. I want to plot the lines between the reggression line and the points

Comment: Maybe you want something like this? https://www.r-bloggers.com/visualising-residuals/